# Performance of active port - netstat

Tags: linux, iptables, performance, netstat, firewalld

Below command

```
    [root@machine1 output]# netstat -s --udp
    IcmpMsg:
        InType0: 371137
        InType3: 296
        InType8: 386843
        InType11: 4
        InType13: 141
        InType15: 1
        InType17: 49
        InType37: 16
        OutType0: 386783
        OutType3: 32599
        OutType8: 362140
        OutType14: 81
        OutType69: 9453
    Udp:
        817280 packets received
        35616 packets to unknown port received.
        0 packet receive errors
        719370 packets sent
        0 receive buffer errors
        0 send buffer errors
    UdpLite:
    IpExt:
        InBcastPkts: 164884
        InOctets: 183199850306
        OutOctets: 262639339161
        InBcastOctets: 86010324
        InNoECTPkts: 180536251
        InECT0Pkts: 7283
    [root@machine1 output]#
```

gives packets(`817280`) received at all UDP ports every sec.

---

But, I would like to know the packets received only at specific UDP port 514

Environment: RHEL 7.x

```
[root@machine1 output]# netstat -an | grep 514
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*
```

---

What are the options given to `netstat` to know the packets received at UDP port 514? per unit time...

Comment: do you have an iptables/firewall rule on the host that specifically allows traffic to port 514/udp?

Comment: @JeffSchaller `iptables -nL | grep 514` gives no output

Comment: Similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/211206/117549